# Python web.py template, how to escape (.) dot

Tags: python, templates, escaping, web.py

In web.py template: index.html I wrote:

```
$def with(s)
<img src="$s.filename.png" />
```

s.filename's value is "picuture" so I want to print

```
<img src="picture.png" />
```

but how can I tell web.py templating system do not to use $s.filename.png  just use $s.filename and add ".png" to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Templetor docs](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor#expressionsubstitution):

> Expression can be enclosed in () or {} for explicit grouping.

So, in your case,

```
<img src="${s.filename}.png" />
```